# How can I programmatically get a list of MacOS's built-in keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, defaults

I've read about ways to manipulate `com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` to manage custom keyboard shortcuts, but if I understand correctly, this is just overwriting built-in shortcuts. If you delete the file, then MacOS's keyboard shortcuts return to their built-ins.

What I would like to do is get a definitive list of MacOS's built-in keyboard shortcuts and their corresponding action identifiers.

Is there somewhere I can pull this from?

Comment: Don’t these change dynamically based on which apps run? Is this about reading the finder settings on a new system?

Comment: I mean the keyboard shortcuts for the OS itself, e.g. Lock Screen : control command Q

Comment: If it helps frame the problem any, I would like to be able to programmatically generate something like this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Comment: That is an amazing product or project!  I wonder if the app that displays all active presses is open source. (Can’t recall the name)

Comment: Do you mean Karabiner-EventViewer? That watches for keystrokes and application focus, but it stops short of being aware of what actual command was execute in the OS or app. E.g. it will know you pressed control command Q, but not that it triggered 'Lock Screen'